# Frequency of matplotlib.pyplot is not integer?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to use matplotlib.pyplot to plot the histogram of an array. This array looks like:

> 0.00759973  0.01399929  0.01979953  0.0263557   0.02830635  0.03270312  ...

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(probabilities, 50, normed = True)      # probabilities store a series of float numbers
plt.xlabel("Success Probability")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

I expect to see a histogram with integer Y-ticks. However, I got this:

[image]

As you could see from the image, the Y-ticks are decimal numbers. I am confused with such outcoming. May I know how can I achieve what I expected? Thanks.

PS: I don't know why the image is not displayed. I tried few times, even replaced the default description... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set argument `normed = False`, because the default value of `normed` is False, you can omit it. Here is the document of `normed`:

> normed : boolean, optional, default: False
>
> If True, the first element of the return tuple will be the counts normalized to form a probability density, i.e., n/(len(x)`dbin), ie
>   the integral of the histogram will sum to 1. If stacked is also True,
>   the sum of the histograms is normalized to 1.